# Dialog box opens when quitting XLSM, DisplayAlerts does not work

Tags: python, excel, exit, win32com, xlsm

When the application closes, the display pops up if I want to save the file. I don't want to save the file and want it to automatically close.

I thought `DisplayAlerts = False` would do the job, but it won't work

```
if os.path.exists("file_name.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("file_name.xlsm"))
    xl.Application.Run("module.module")
    sht.range('A1').value = 11
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False 
    xl.Application.Quit() 
    del xl
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Quit):

> If unsaved workbooks are open when you use this method, Microsoft Excel displays a dialog box asking whether you want to save the changes. You can prevent this by saving all workbooks before using the Quit method or by setting the [**DisplayAlerts**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) property to **False**. When this property is **False**, Microsoft Excel doesn't display the dialog box when you quit with unsaved workbooks; it quits without saving them.
>
> If you set the [**Saved**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saved) property for a workbook to **True** without saving the workbook to the disk, Microsoft Excel will quit without asking you to save the workbook.

That is, what you're doing *should* work, and indeed works completely fine in my testing (just opening Excel through COM, setting `xl.Visible` to `True`, creating a new workbook, changing it, and trying to close the application with and without `DisplayAlerts` set to `False`).

From here, you could try to

- set `Saved` to `True` for each open workbook, as suggested by the documentation, or
- let `Application.EnableEvents = False`,

prior to quitting.